# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException error when decoding object from archive in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, foundation

Please note that I'm really new to Swift and iOS programming so some of you may find this a bit silly.

Anyway, so I am encoding an `Int` object and associating it with a `String` key like so:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    // Note that `rating` is an Int
    aCoder.encodeObject(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.ratingKey)

}
```

**Now when I try to decode it like so:**

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let rating = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.ratingKey)

    // Initialising a model class
    self.init(rating: rating)
}
```

The constant `rating` is expected to an `Int` because `decodeIntegerForKey` is expected to return an `Int` by default

Build goes well, but it crashes when I run it and logs an error as replicated below.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', 
reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeInt64ForKey:]: 
value for key (rating) is not an integer number'
```

**But** it seems to work well when I change `decodeIntegerForKey` to `decodeObjectForKey` and downcast the return value to an `Int`.

Like so:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // Replaced `decodeInteger` with `decodeObject` and downcasting the return value to Int 
    let rating = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.ratingKey) as! Int
    self.init(rating: rating)
}
```

It is getting hard for me to understand why the exception, because I encoded it as an `Int` and `decodeInteger` returns an Int by default.

Also, I feel like the `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException` is telling me that I've used the wrong operation to decode the encoded object out.

This isn't making any sense to me, help

Comment: I'm not sure for Swift what the right answer is but, when you say "I encoded it as an Int", that not entirely accurate.  You're using `aCoder.encodeObject` not the `Integer` version.

Comment: @PhillipMills Hey, thanks so much. I just noticed. I should have used `aCoder.encodeInteger` instead of `aCoder.encodeObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been resolved. Thanks to @PhillipMills for clarifying.

The implementation was done wrong while encoding the `Int` object. I was encoding it in `AnyObject` instead of `Int` and was trying to decode it as an `Int`. And that's why I had to downcast it and decoding as an `Int` wasn't working.

Encoding should have been done like so:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    // Note that `rating` is an Int
    aCoder.encodeInteger(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.ratingKey)

}
```